# How to Get JSON array which will be later stored in Realm table?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, api

This is part of JSON my API returns, I don't know how to get that and store in Realm table?

```
 "images": {
                "image1": {
                    "url": "http://www.example.com/900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72.gif",
"path": "data/2clb91218/900150983aassfb0d6963f7d28e17f72.gif",
                "alt": "YWJj"
                },
                "image2": {
                    "url": "http://example/tex/fbce4a1ebe576539394e9493e30c7e5e.gif",
"path": "data/2clb91218/900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e332g22.gif",
                "alt": "Yaaase22"
                },
                "image3": {
                    "url": "https://example.amazonaws.com/card/480_300/9/9jpul1218.jpg",
    "path": "data/2clb91218/ewfregwrgw6963f7d28e17f72.gif",
                "alt": "pic3"
                }
            }
```

*NOTE :* Dont test these urls, I didnt want to put real ones.
*NOTE :* In object 'Images', child-object's names are chaning so we have: 'image1' , 'image2' etc.
I have read on Stackoverflow that for storing arrays in RealmTable, we need to use non-dynamic List<> , so this is how I store image-urls in class:

```
var images = List<String>()
```

This is part of my responseJSON function where I am trying to Get images from API, 'continue' is there just to Get another objects if images are unable to Get :

```
guard let images = data["images"] as? [String: Any?],
                     let image = images["image1"] as? [String: String], 
                     let imageUrl = image["url"] as?  String
                 else { print("error") ; continue }
```

This above works for 'image1', but what about other image names, how to handle them?
And one more problem - 'Images' object can return NIL if there are no images which can aslo happen. If it's nil, I want to put "null" in RealmTable's column 'images' of the type I mentioned above. 
I hope you can fully understand me, if not, comment and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
guard let images = data["images"] as? [String:[String:Any]] else { return }
let res = Array(images.values)
let urls = res.compactMap { $0["url"] as? String }
print("All urls : ",urls)
```

Comment: Hey, are you sure with that data type [String:[String:String]] for guard let images? I debugged and it goes to *else* every time.

Comment: ok do `let images = data["images"] as! [String:[String:String]]`  and post the crash here also is that the full json no more nested keys ???

Comment: This is crash error : Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x7fff87b9dcb8) to 'NSDictionary'
No, except 'url' there are two more keys, I thought I dont need to post them here because I dont want to get them. Maybe I should have posted.. Sorry, will be edited in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var images = List<String>()
 let imagesDictInfo = responseData.toDictionary()
    if let imageArray = imagesDictInfo["Images"] as? [[String:Any]]{
       let imageArrayData = image.getJson()
      //Store this ImageArray into realm or

        for image in imageArray{ 
           let imageData = image.getJson()
           //Store Image Data 
            images.append(imageData)
        }
    }

    func getJson(_ jsonString:String) -> [String:Any]?{
       do{
         let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
          if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
                     return json
             }else{
                return nil
             }
         }catch{
             return nil
           }
     }

    func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
       let blankDict : NSDictionary = [:]
       if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
          do {
             return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary
          } catch {
              print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
         }
       return blankDict
   }
```